# JWT bearer token authorization with no database access, use service/repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-authorization

I have an API with controller-service-repository pattern.
I want to implement JWT bearer token authorization so I created an `AuthenticationController`.
The rest of my application flows from the controller which calls the service which calls the repository.
However, I am not accessing the database for authentication and I'm only accessing configuration data so I only have a controller and no service/repository.
Is it recommended to implement this way or is it better to include the service/repository even though I'm not accessing the database to make it consistent?

This is my `AuthenticationController`:

```
[Route("api/Authentication")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get { return _config; } }

    public AuthenticationController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    [Route("Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody] UserLogin userLogin)
    {
        var user = AuthenticateUser(userLogin);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var token = GenerateToken();
            return Ok(token);
        }

        return NotFound("User not found");
    }

    private UserModel AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
    {
        UserModel user = new UserModel()
        {
            ClientID = _config["Claims:ClientID"],
            ClientSecret = _config["Claims:ClientSecret"]
        };

        if (user.ClientID == userLogin.ClientID && 
            user.ClientSecret == userLogin.ClientSecret)
        {
            return user;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string GenerateToken()
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim("client_id", _config["Claims:ClientID"]),
            new Claim("client_secret", _config["Claims:ClientSecret"]),
            new Claim("grant_type", _config["Claims:GrantType"]),
            new Claim("scope", _config["Claims:Scope"]),
        };

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                                         _config["Jwt:Audience"],
                                         claims,
                                         expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
                                         signingCredentials: credentials);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is no need to use repository here. You could create just the service alone.

You don't always have to follow service/repository pattern, unless you really have need for such level of abstraction.

In fact in many cases you can just get away with IMediator's CommandHandlers with injected DbContext. Read more here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126